# How can I found all secure and third party cookies on any website using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, third-party-cookies

I was tried different approach to get secure and third party cookies. Pasting approach I was tried.

With cookiesjar:

```
import urllib
import http.cookiejar

url = "https://www.google.com"

cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
url_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
url_opener.open(url)

for cookie in cookie_jar:
    print(cookie)
```

with Requests module:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')

for cookie in r.cookies:
  print(cookie.__dict__)
  print(cookie.secure)
```

with PhantomJS:

```
from selenium import webdriver

cookie_file_path = 'cookie.txt'

args = ['--cookies-file={}'.format(cookie_file_path)]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=args)
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.get('http://facebook.com')
with open(cookie_file_path) as f:
   print(f.read())
```

with Selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_exe, options=options,  desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://google.com')
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
   print(cookie)
```

Any help or docs related to this would be appriacted.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use selenium devtool to extract all the cookies present on the website.

Ref:
[1]: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you cookies?

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
```

Comment: yes but only HttpOnly cookies not the secure one.